# How to use implode in where clause for columns' values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Part of JSON string before decode: `,"avail":["Wed-2","Wed-3"]`

decoded : `$data = json_decode($return, true);`
stored in variable : `$avail = $data['avail'];`

//array declarations

```
$days = array();
$cols = array();
```

Format above `$avail:`

```
     if($avail != ""){
        foreach($avail as $k=>$v)
        {
            echo $v;

            $array = explode('-', $v);
            $day =$array[0]; // Wed
            $column =  $array[1]; // 2

            if($column == 1)
            {
            $col = "morning";

            }
            if($column == 2)
            {
                $col = "afternoon";
            }
            if($column == 3)
            {
                $col = "evening";
            }
             echo $col ."=>". $day;

            array_push($cols,$col);
            array_push($days,$day);
        }
        }
```

//Now use the array($days) to match values for column 'morning' in the posts table.

```
echo $sql=" SELECT * , (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(('$lat' - lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS('$lat' * pi()/180) * COS(lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(('$lon' - lon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) as distance  
from posts,subjects WHERE posts.afternoon IN (" . implode(", ",$days) . ") AND posts.catID = '$catid' AND posts.subname LIKE '%$subject%' AND posts.subid = subjects.subid AND posts.catID = subjects.catid  AND posts.pricing <= '$rate'  having  distance <= '$distance' order by distance ";
echo"<br/>";
        $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
$place=array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
               $place[] = $row;
               }

var_dump($place);
```

But it returned this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Wed' in
>   'where clause'' in C:\wamp\www\fetch_tutor.php on line 128 ( ! )
>   PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'Wed' in 'where clause' in C:\wamp\www\fetch_tutor.php on line 128

Based on this, I understood the array ($day) supplied is taken as field name. In fact that's the value in array to check in the 'morning' field in posts table.

How do I do that please.I've wasted almost a day on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
WHERE posts.afternoon IN ('" . implode("',' ",$days) . "')
```

to get something like `WHERE posts.afternoon IN ('Mon','Wed','Sun')`.

Comment: Shouldn't there also be single quotes at the beginning and at the end? Like `IN ('" . implode("',' ",$days) . "')`?